# Minishift/openshift node application with db connection string

Tags: openshift, minishift

I've a nodejs application which connect to mssql using the connection string defined in a json file. Different environment will connect to different db.

In minishift, what is the proper way to pass the json config file to different container at runtime?

Regards, nww

Answer (score 0):

First, define this json file as a configmap. You can do it on web UI (under Resources/Config Maps) or command line, for example:

```
oc create configmap mssql1 --from-file=json=/path/to/your/json
```

Secondly, mount the configmap onto your nodejs deployment. You can do it on web UI (find your nodejs deployment, switch to `Configuration` tab, and click `Add Config Files` link).